# How to do an option menu under the action bar in one fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, optionmenu

I'm developing a social Android app, in which I have three fragments. In my second fragment (friends), I want to have an options menu (search, contacts, etc.)

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Well, start with searching for method onCreateOptionsMenu in documentation.

Comment: Thank you , i will see this method .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement Pageviewer here is example [ViewPager](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)

add in viewpager library in xml file

```
          <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

herre is instance of viewpager in oncreate method of your Mainactivity

```
          viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mAdapter = new MultiPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    GetAllApplications();

    custmAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, systemAppsInfo);
    init();
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
    viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            viewPager.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Adapter for the pager is here

```
        public class MultiPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public MultiPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 1:
        // Top Rated fragment activity
        return new ApplicationsFragment();
    case 2:
        // Games fragment activity
        return new SearchAppFragment();
    case 0:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new RecentAppsFragment();
    }


    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}
```

}

here is fragment where your search is implemented

```
public class SearchAppFragment extends Fragment {
Utitlity utitlity;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sec_fragment, container, false);
    final EditText editSearch = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_search_fragment);
    ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.app_list);
    final CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getContext(), MainActivity.systemAppsInfo);
    utitlity = new Utitlity(getContext());
    lv.setAdapter(customAdapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            try {
                Intent LaunchIntent = getContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(MainActivity.systemAppsInfo.get(position).getPname());
                startActivity(LaunchIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,but i already have my 3 fragments i'm trying to do an option menu in one of my fragments ,see the image that i posted .